# Is there any deeper reason behind the conservation of mass?

Tags: mass, conservation-laws

I have read that behind the conservation of energy or momentum is the Noether theorem with its intimidating maths.

Is there any similar deeper foundation behind the conservation of mass?

Comment: mass isn't conserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mass is not a conserved quantity, except in classical mechanics and its derivatives. As classical mechanics emerges from quantum mechanics and special relativity the conservations laws on energy and momentum, Noether's theorem in quantum mechanical terms, define also the mass. Everything has energy and momentum and is described by a [fourvector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html), and the "length" of that four vector is the invariant mass of a particle . Vector algebra has to be used for systems of particles, and the summed vector's length gives the invariant mass of the system